# Postgres, split one row into multiple rows with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table order_item like this:

```
  | sku | quantity | subtotal |
  |-----|----------|----------|
  |  A  |        1 |   25.00  |
  |  B  |        2 |   40.00  |
  |  C  |        3 |   45.00  |
```

Is there any way to select "unit order_item" rows from order_item with result like:

```
  | sku | unit_price |
  |-----|------------|
  |  A  |   25.00    |
  |  B  |   20.00    |
  |  B  |   20.00    |
  |  C  |   15.00    |
  |  C  |   15.00    |
  |  C  |   15.00    |
```

where the result row counts of a sku is the quantity in order_item and the unit_price is (subtotal/quantity) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
select oi.sku, oi.subtotal / oi.quantity as unit_price
from order_item oi
  cross join lateral generate_series(1,oi.quantity)
order by oi.sku;
```